# Angular10 , Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined at d3.js

Tags: angular, plotly.js

After upgrading from angular8 to angular 10. I'm getting following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined at d3.js".
```

I think it may be connected with plotly.js lib that I added just before upgrading to angular10. Anybody struggled with similar error?

Comment: It seems that Angular10 doesn't support plotly.js. Switching to chart.js fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [this github](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/issues/75) issue, this is an error when bundling the d3.js which is inside the plotly.js code. Angular 10 removed the `es5` option, making it not possible to bundle d3.js correctly.

The simplest solution would be using the [`PlotlyViaCDNModule`](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js#plotly-via-cdn-module) or [`PlotlyViaWindowModule`](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js#plotly-via-window-module) to not bundle it while building the project.